# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - invalid sql statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am programming an application in java, which exits of an .sql file in the project. This project is connected to an oracle db. In the sql file I am trying to execute the statement

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE /path/to/file REPLACE...`

but this is not working. I already know that this command is for MySQL but how can I use this in my example? I got the exception that , that is an invalid sql statement.

Comment: There is no such command in Oracle and there is no equivalent SQL command for that. You need to use e.g. the SQL\*Loader command line tool

Comment: So I can't call this in my java application? And how can I load the lines in the code otherwise?

Comment: @Lia read the last sentence of a_horse_with_no_name's comment again....

Comment: @ADyson thx got it. But how can I do it otherwise with the sql loader ? I read something about a "oracle loader" which I can use .. is that something similar ?

Comment: `https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ` is probably a place to start. It's been years since I used oracle but it's not hard to find this stuff on Google. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm too